# Unable start qt creator on ubuntu

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I did install qt creator in ubuntu 14.04 using Ubuntu software center, but whenever i click on icon it just flashes but will not start, can please someone tell me the solution so that i can fix this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you run `qtcreator` from the commandline and post the terminal output in your original question?

Comment: hi andrew,  i have got the solution, the problem was that ubuntu sdk wasn't installed. now it is working for me. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear :)